# Moving mod_rewrite rules in .htaccess to httpd.conf

Tags: regex, optimization

I've got a massive set of URL rewriting rules that I am trying to:

1. optimize
2. transition to use within httpd.conf

But I'm facing problems in getting the final product to work.

Note: There are optimizations that others have mentioned at: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4237/url-rewritten-pages-take-much-longer-to- (please DO have a look at this)

Note: The following works perfectly within a .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /abcd/

RewriteRule ^.*/codelibrary/(.*)$ codelibrary/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^.*/instructor_upload/images/(.*)$ instructor_upload/images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^.*/content/image/(.*)$ content/image/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^.*/content/video/(.*)$ content/video/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !instructor_upload/(.*)\.
RewriteRule ^.*/images/(.*)$ images/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^.*/flowplayer/(.*)$ flowplayer/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^.*/admin/ajax/(.*)$ admin/ajax/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !admin/(.*)\.
RewriteRule ^.*/ajax/(.*)$ ajax/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^.*/banner_images/(.*)$ banner_images/$1 [L]

RewriteRule (.*)invite/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ referer.php?instructor_name=$2 [L]
RewriteRule (.*)class/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ class-profile.php?class_id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule (.*)event/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ event-profile.php?event_id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule (.*)content/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\s]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\s]*)/(.*)$ content-profile.php?content_id=$2&$4=$5 [L]
RewriteRule (.*)content/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ content-profile.php?content_id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule (.*)cms/([a-zA-Z\-\s]*).html$ static-pages.php?page_url=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ teacher-profile-public.php?name=$1

RewriteRule (.*)cms/([a-zA-Z\-]*).html$ static-pages.php?page_url=$2 [L]

RewriteRule (.*)classes-events.html$ browse.php?type=classes-events [L]
RewriteRule (.*)instructors.html$ browse.php?type=instructors [L]
RewriteRule (.*)organizations.html$ browse.php?type=organizations [L]
RewriteRule (.*)random-content.html$ browse.php?type=content&random_order=1 [L]
RewriteRule (.*)content.html$ browse.php?type=content [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z\-]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\s]*)/([0-9]*)\.html$ browse.php?type=$1&catId=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z\-]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\s]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\s]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)\.html$ browse.php?type=$1&catId=$4&subCatId=$5 [L]

RewriteRule (.*)search/all/(.*)$ searchall.php?type=all&srcval=$2 [L]
RewriteRule (.*)search/([a-zA-Z\s\-]*)/all/(.*)$ search.php?type=$2&srcval=$3&seeall=all [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !all/(.*)\.
RewriteRule (.*)search/([a-zA-Z\s\-]*)/(.*)$ search.php?type=$2&srcval=$3 [L]
RewriteRule (.*)featured/([a-zA-Z\s\-]*)/(.*)/([0-9]*)\.html$ featured-listing.php?type=$2&catId=$4&feature=1 [L]
RewriteRule (.*)featured/(.*)$ featured-listing.php?type=$2&feature=1 [L]
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/abcd/404.php
```

The following does NOT work fine within a httpd.conf

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/abcd/.*/codelibrary/(.*)$ /abcd/codelibrary/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/abcd/.*/instructor_upload/images/(.*)$ /abcd/instructor_upload/images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/abcd/.*/content/image/(.*)$ /abcd/content/image/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/abcd/.*/content/video/(.*)$ /abcd/content/video/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !abcd/instructor_upload/(.*)\.
RewriteRule ^/abcd/.*/images/(.*)$ /abcd/images/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^/abcd/.*/flowplayer/(.*)$ /abcd/flowplayer/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/abcd/.*/admin/ajax/(.*)$ /abcd/admin/ajax/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !abcd/admin/(.*)\.
RewriteRule ^/abcd/.*/ajax/(.*)$ /abcd/ajax/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^/abcd/.*/banner_images/(.*)$ /abcd/banner_images/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^/abcd/invite/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ /abcd/referer.php?instructor_name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/abcd/class/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /abcd/class-profile.php?class_id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/abcd/event/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /abcd/event-profile.php?event_id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/abcd/content/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /abcd/content-profile.php?content_id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/abcd/cms/([a-zA-Z\-\s]*).html$ /abcd/static-pages.php?page_url=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/abcd/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ /abcd/teacher-profile-public.php?name=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^/abcd/cms/([a-zA-Z\-]*).html$ /abcd/static-pages.php?page_url=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^/abcd/classes-events.html$ /abcd/browse.php?type=classes-events [L]
RewriteRule ^/abcd/instructors.html$ /abcd/browse.php?type=instructors [L]
RewriteRule ^/abcd/organizations.html$ /abcd/browse.php?type=organizations [L]
RewriteRule ^/abcd/random-content.html$ /abcd/browse.php?type=content&random_order=1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/abcd/content.html$ /abcd/browse.php?type=content [L]

RewriteRule ^/abcd/([a-zA-Z\-]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\s]*)/([0-9]*)\.html$ /abcd/browse.php?type=$1&catId=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^/abcd/([a-zA-Z\-]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\s]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\s]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)\.html$ /abcd/browse.php?type=$1&catId=$4&subCatId=$5 [L]

RewriteRule ^/abcd/search/all/(.*)$ /abcd/searchall.php?type=all&srcval=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/abcd/search/([a-zA-Z\s\-]*)/all/(.*)$ /abcd/search.php?type=$1&srcval=$2&seeall=all [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !abcd/all/(.*)\.
RewriteRule ^/abcd/search/([a-zA-Z\s\-]*)/(.*)$ /abcd/search.php?type=$1&srcval=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/abcd/featured/([a-zA-Z\s\-]*)/(.*)/([0-9]*)\.html$ /abcd/featured-listing.php?type=$1&catId=$3&feature=1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/abcd/featured/(.*)$ /abcd/featured-listing.php?type=$1&feature=1 [L]
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/abcd/404.php
```

Comment: Is this something for here?  I'd think Server Fault would be a better place for this question.

Comment: @Mark - it is a code review question. Its not stereotypical code, I give you that - but code nevertheless for which I could use your input! :)

Comment: see http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/180/is-this-really-code

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to leave this here:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Context: server config, virtual host, **directory**, .htaccess

( https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/directive-dict.html#Context )

Comment: @user972 - thanks. How is this useful?

Answer (score -1):

Probably you should include httpd.conf to apache2.conf

Go to /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and add

```
Include httpd.conf
```

there.

After that restart apache.

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question. Not all flavours of Linux use apache2.conf in any case.

Comment: It may answer the original question. And may not. It depends on whether httpd.conf already included or not. Are you disagree on that? And of course, you are right about "not all flavours of Linux use apache2.conf", thanks!

Comment: And I did not noticed it was 2011 year`s question. Will be more careful next time.

Comment: It's possible but a bit unlikely. And as you say, it's an old question. Welcome to SF!